# Kenmore Water Dispenser Replace Parts

Tags: refrigerator

I have a Kenmore Elite 795.79753.904 refrigerator and have owned this for almost 12 years. I want to replace the rubber parts of the water dispenser as they look moldy. Specifically the water tube and whatever tubing is used to connect it to the previous part which is likely a switch of some sort.

I found that this is actually an LG refrigerator and that 79753 is the model number. I can't find a proper service manual for this refrigerator and I can't find a parts diagram that shows this tubing. Can anyone help me find a service manual that shows how to disassemble the dispenser and also what part numbers I need? If the parts are not available I could always take it a part and at least soak these parts in vinegar to clean them but I would still like a service manual so I can see how to disassemble this.

Thanks in advance.

#### Edit

The part I want to replace is shown in picture 3. It is a gray flex tube and I cannot find it online or listed in any part breakdown diagram.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: try this https://www.genuinereplacementparts.com/index.php?cPath=367808&active=2009973

Answer (score 1):

Doing a google search for "795.79753.904" brings up many sites with parts diagrams and actual parts for sale. Contacting them may help get a service manual or instruction links. You could also try calling the phone number on the label.

Here is a sample set of water dispenser switches shown from googling:

[image]

Comment: I had gotten this far already. The question I had was is there someone that has a service manual or location where I can download it and where can I find the rubber part(s) where the water part that I can see (hard to see in picture but it's gray and flexible). That rubber part cannot be found by me anywhere online and also not in any of the images you have shown in your answer. I was hoping the service manual would have more information about where to get this part or what the part number even is.

Comment: I edited my question with a better pic. of the part that I am unable to find and also not able to find in any parts diagram.

Comment: @Igor What did the various companies suggest when you talked with them on the phone or email?